# Is there a generalize-able relationship between Ecell and T for a galvanic cell?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

Is there a generalize-able relationship between Ecell and T for a galvanic cell (assuming constant concentrations of all components)? (ie: higher temp = bigger/smaller Voltage)

Or is it entirely dependant on the underpinning thermodynamics - ie: if a given galvanic cell is -∆Srxn, then it will become LESS spontaneous at higher T, thus lower Ecell (&vice versa)?

And does this have anything to do with the two other temperature & electricity relationships I know of - as T increases, R increases; & storing batteries in the fridge makes them last longer? Or are both of those totally unrelated to Ecell (/is the fridge one an old wives tale?)

Answer (score 0):

You apply $ \pu{\Delta G = - zE_{cell}F = \Delta H - T \Delta S}$. If the chosen temperature is not too far away from $25°C$, it makes sense to consider that $\pu{\Delta H}$ and $\pu{\Delta S}$ are constant. As $\pu{z}$ and $\pu{F}$ are constant, applying this formula gives the cell potential $\pu{E_{cell}}$ at any temperature.

Comment: Awesome. That is exactly the connection my brain was missing. Thank you so much! Much easier to see the relationship in this formulation than in Nernst! :)

Comment: The above stays for the equilibrium. If current is involved, not only thermodynamics, but kinetics must be involved as well. Like charge transfer rates of electrode reactions, ion mobility, molar conductivity, diffusion coefficients....  The topic is rather a scope for a long article or a small book.